# What is the latency of alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I've developed a Alexa skill which communicate to my device through web socket and fetch some data. I'm getting 1689.847 ms in my logs to complete an API request. But on Alexa device its taking 3-4 seconds to respond back.  Any one knows what is the minimum or maximum time for response.

Answer (score 0):

In Lambda you can extend your execution time here

[image: To extend]

But it is not a good practice to make users wait for more than 3 to 5 seconds for the response. And the Alexa default timeout is 8 seconds so it automatically exits the skill if there is no response within 8 seconds.